# amazon about get audio stream in real-time

Tags: amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I am using Amazon Connect services, and I have used Lambda function blocks, as well as Start Media Streaming and Stop Media Streaming blocks in my contact flow. My goal is to capture real-time voice stream during phone conversations. The official documentation suggests using the GetMedia API for this purpose. However, I encountered an error in the response.
The exception is MissingAuthenticationTokenException.

So how do get the voice stream in real-time？